# How to define function inside the argument of a function that takes function as argument

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
void print(void func(int)){
  func(6);
}
int main(){
  print(void ext(int r){
  std::cout<<r;
  });
  return 0;
}
```

i want to define a function inside the parameter itself instead of defining it somewhere else and using its name as parameter. Like in javascripts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11 or later, you can do that with a lambda:

```
print([](int r){std::cout << r;});
```

Since `print` takes a plain function pointer, you're restricted to simple stateless lambdas like this one; you can't capture anything. You might like to give it more flexibility through polymorphism, either using a template:

```
template <typename Function>
void print(Function func) {
    func(6);
}
```

or type erasure:

```
void print(std::function<void(int)> func) {
    func(6);
}
```

Comment: "You might like to give it more flexibility through polymorphism, either using a template" Suggest change: "You might like to give it more flexibility using a polymorphic function wrapper or a template"

Comment: @Deduplicator: I regard both as forms of polymorphism (static and dynamic respectively), so I'll leave the wording it as it is.

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy with two new new features in C++11: [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
void print(std::function<void(int)> func)
{
    func(6);
}

int main()
{
    print([](int r){ std::cout << r; });
}
```

---

With `std::function` you can use *any* callable object, not only lambda expressions.

For example:

```
// The `print` function as above

void print_num(int r)
{
    std::cout << r;
}

int main()
{
    print(print_num);
}
```

Or

```
// The `print` function as above

struct printer
{
    void operator()(int r)
    {
        std::cout << r;
    }
};

int main()
{
    print(printer());  // Creates a temporary object
}
```

Comment: You don't need `std::function`. Capture-less lambdas convert to function pointers.

Comment: @leemes Yes, but what about other callable objects, like shown in my last example?

Comment: Yes then it makes sense (yet a template can be a better solution in some cases, especially if the function is called immediately), but I was specifically talking about the lambda. And the other examples are not "literally inline" as it was the whole intent of the question, isn't it? ;) (It is good to provide alternatives, however.)